# Помогите расшифровать Crash Log для iOS (прислали Apple)

Tags: objective-c, ios, логирование, ios7

У нас все работает, а Apple не принимает в App Store, говорят, что вылетает после авторизации через ВК. Как это происходит: они нажимают "Войти" -> открывается webVeiw -> после входа webView закрывается и приложение вылетает. Не понятно почему, они выслали crash log, но я не уверен, что все понимаю:

P.S. Я сделал Symbolicate через XCode и получил более детальный Crash Log:

Можно увидеть backtrace исключения:

```
Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x18523a59c __exceptionPreprocess + 132
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x195e940e4 objc_exception_throw + 60
2   CoreFoundation                  0x185128798 -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:] + 420
3   CoreFoundation                  0x1851285c8 +[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:forKeys:count:] + 72
4   Lime                            0x1000a94a4 0x1000a0000 + 38052
5   Lime                            0x1000be2ec 0x1000a0000 + 123628
6   Lime                            0x1000bd710 0x1000a0000 + 120592
7   Lime                            0x1000be570 0x1000a0000 + 124272
8   CFNetwork                       0x184cdee70 __65-[NSURLConnectionInternal _withConnectionAndDelegate:onlyActive:]_block_invoke + 80
9   CFNetwork                       0x184cdee00 -[NSURLConnectionInternal _withConnectionAndDelegate:onlyActive:] + 208
10  CFNetwork                       0x184cdef7c -[NSURLConnectionInternal _withActiveConnectionAndDelegate:] + 60
11  CFNetwork                       0x184bb38e4 ___ZN27URLConnectionClient_Classic26_delegate_didFinishLoadingEU13block_pointerFvvE_block_invoke + 104
12  CFNetwork                       0x184c7c540 ___ZN27URLConnectionClient_Classic18_withDelegateAsyncEPKcU13block_pointerFvP16_CFURLConnectionPK33CFURLConnectionClientCurrent_VMaxE_block_invoke_2 + 104
13  CFNetwork                       0x184b9fb54 RunloopBlockContext::_invoke_block(void const*, void*) + 76
14  CoreFoundation                  0x18511caac CFArrayApplyFunction + 68
15  CFNetwork                       0x184b9fa00 RunloopBlockContext::perform() + 136
16  CFNetwork                       0x184b9f8b4 MultiplexerSource::perform() + 312
17  CFNetwork                       0x184b9f6e0 MultiplexerSource::_perform(void*) + 68
18  CoreFoundation                  0x1851f29ec __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
19  CoreFoundation                  0x1851f1c90 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 264
20  CoreFoundation                  0x1851efd40 __CFRunLoopRun + 712
21  CoreFoundation                  0x18511d0a4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 396
22  GraphicsServices                0x18e2a35a4 GSEventRunModal + 168
23  UIKit                           0x189a4eaa4 UIApplicationMain + 1488
24  Lime                            0x1000a74cc 0x1000a0000 + 29900
25  libdyld.dylib                   0x196502a08 start + 4

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019661b270 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001966b9224 pthread_kill + 108
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0000000196592b14 abort + 108
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000195665414 abort_message + 112
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000195684b88 default_terminate_handler() + 300
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000000195e943bc _objc_terminate() + 124
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000195681bb0 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 12
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000195681474 __cxa_throw + 132
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000000195e94200 objc_exception_throw + 344
9   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185128794 -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:] + 416
10  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001851285c4 +[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:forKeys:count:] + 68
11  Lime                            0x00000001000a94a0 0x1000a0000 + 38048
12  Lime                            0x00000001000be2e8 0x1000a0000 + 123624
13  Lime                            0x00000001000bd70c 0x1000a0000 + 120588
14  Lime                            0x00000001000be56c 0x1000a0000 + 124268
15  CFNetwork                       0x0000000184cdee6c __65-[NSURLConnectionInternal _withConnectionAndDelegate:onlyActive:]_block_invoke + 76
16  CFNetwork                       0x0000000184cdedfc -[NSURLConnectionInternal _withConnectionAndDelegate:onlyActive:] + 204
17  CFNetwork                       0x0000000184cdef78 -[NSURLConnectionInternal _withActiveConnectionAndDelegate:] + 56
18  CFNetwork                       0x0000000184bb38e0 ___ZN27URLConnectionClient_Classic26_delegate_didFinishLoadingEU13block_pointerFvvE_block_invoke + 100
19  CFNetwork                       0x0000000184c7c53c ___ZN27URLConnectionClient_Classic18_withDelegateAsyncEPKcU13block_pointerFvP16_CFURLConnectionPK33CFURLConnectionClientCurrent_VMaxE_block_invoke_2 + 100
20  CFNetwork                       0x0000000184b9fb50 RunloopBlockContext::_invoke_block(void const*, void*) + 72
21  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018511caa8 CFArrayApplyFunction + 64
22  CFNetwork                       0x0000000184b9f9fc RunloopBlockContext::perform() + 132
23  CFNetwork                       0x0000000184b9f8b0 MultiplexerSource::perform() + 308
24  CFNetwork                       0x0000000184b9f6dc MultiplexerSource::_perform(void*) + 64
25  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001851f29e8 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 20
26  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001851f1c8c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 260
27  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001851efd3c __CFRunLoopRun + 708
28  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018511d0a0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 392
29  GraphicsServices                0x000000018e2a35a0 GSEventRunModal + 164
30  UIKit                           0x0000000189a4eaa0 UIApplicationMain + 1484
31  Lime                            0x00000001000a74c8 0x1000a0000 + 29896
32  libdyld.dylib                   0x0000000196502a04 start + 0
```

Comment: @Tony, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Падение в 0 потоке, но чтобы понять точнее надо чтобы понять на ем именно надо открыть в том же xcode что вы собирали и сделать symbolycate (или что-то типа того). "У на работает, у эппл нет" получается запросто, причины когда-то расписывал тут hashcode.ru/questions/320095/

Comment: Я обновил Crash Log в шапке - в общем, сделал Symbolicate лога и получил более детализированную - гляньте еще раз, пожалуйста.

Там на бэктрейсе видно, что URLConnection, initWithDictionary и т.д. Может ли это быть связано с тем, что я получаю ответ ВК и при попытке записать их в Dictionary попадают nil'ы, например?.. Просто непонятно, какие nil'ы могут быть… ВК либо вернет ошибку, либо данные (в нашем случае), до ошибки дело не доходит - значит верный response, но в нем все поля присутствуют...

P.S. Спасибо за ответ, почитал в той ветке, пока разбираюсь

Comment: Самую интересную часть и не распознало - что именно творится в приложении.
По поводу ВК - последние года полтора с ним не работал, но раньше у него помимо ошибок или данных еще иногда капча приходила если он считал что бот лезет, что там с респонсом было уже не помню. Ваш код это учитывает?